# How does "concatMap" from mono-traversable is able to "pull out" common argument?

Tags: haskell, traversal

I am learning Haskell and was doing a simple DB-seed program for Yesod when I stumbled upon this behavior which I find hard to understand:

```hs
testFn :: Int -> Bool -> [Int]
testFn a b = if b then replicate 10 a else []
```

Yesod GHCI session:

```
$ :t concatMap testFn [3]
concatMap testFn [3] :: Bool -> [Int]
$ (concatMap testFn [1,2,3]) True
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
```

Somehow it was able to "pull" out that second "Bool" from each of mappings into a single curried argument.

Standard base Prelude GHCI session refuses to even compile this expression:

```
$ :t concatMap testFn [3]
error:
    • Couldn't match type 'Bool -> [Int]' with '[b]'
      Expected type: Int -> [b]
        Actual type: Int -> Bool -> [Int]
    • Probable cause: 'testFn' is applied to too few arguments
      In the first argument of 'concatMap', namely 'testFn'
      In the expression: concatMap testFn [3]
```

Turns out Yesod uses [mono-traversable](https://github.com/snoyberg/mono-traversable/tree/master/mono-traversable#readme) library which has its own `concatMap`:

```
$ :t concatMap
concatMap
  :: (MonoFoldable mono, Monoid m) =>
     (Element mono -> m) -> mono -> m
```

At my current level of Haskell understanding I couldn't figure out how types are distributed here. Could someone explain to me (as much beginner oriented as possible) how this trick is done? What part of `testFn` above is conforming to `Element mono` type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We start by listing some types we know. (We pretend that numbers are `Int` for simplicity -- this is not really relevant.)

```
testFn :: Int -> Bool -> [Int]
[1,2,3] :: [Int]
True :: Bool
```

`(concatMap testFn [1,2,3]) True` is the same as `concatMap testFn [1,2,3] True`, so `concatMap` must have a type matching all those arguments:

```
concatMap :: (Int -> Bool -> [Int]) -> [Int] -> Bool -> ???
```

where `???` is the result type. Note that, because of the associativity rules, `->` associates to the right, so the above typing is the same as:

```
concatMap :: (Int -> (Bool -> [Int])) -> [Int] -> (Bool -> ???)
```

Let's write the general type above that one. I am adding a few spaces to mark the similarity.

```
concatMap :: (MonoFoldable mono, Monoid m) =>
             (Element mono -> m              ) -> mono  -> m
concatMap :: (Int          -> (Bool -> [Int])) -> [Int] -> (Bool -> ???)
```

Ah-ha! We have a match if we choose `m` as `Bool -> [Int]`, and `mono` as `[Int]`. If we do so, we do satisfy the constraints `MonoFoldable mono, Monoid m` (see below), and we also have `Element mono ~ Int`, so everything type checks.

We infer that `???` is `[Int]` from the definition of `m`.

About the constraints: for `MonoFoldable [Int]`, there's little to say. `[Int]` is clearly a list-like type with an `Int` element type, and that's enough to make it into a `MonaFoldable` with `Int` as its `Element`.

For `Monoid (Bool -> [Int])`, it a bit more complex. We have that any function type `A -> B` is a monoid if `B` is a monoid. This follows by performing the operation in a pointwise fashion. In our specific case, we rely on `[Int]` being a monoid and we get:

```
mempty :: Bool -> [Int]
mempty = \_ -> []

(<>) :: (Bool -> [Int]) -> (Bool -> [Int]) -> (Bool -> [Int])
f <> g = \b -> f b ++ g b
```

Comment: Great explanation! The way you've explained and aligned types is just what I wanted to see, thanks!